# Get Release Pipeline Execution Status

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the below REST API : Releases - Get Release
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

I am seeing there are multiple status columns for which I do not see clear MSFT documentation.

Can someone help me identify which output / log would identify whether the Release pipeline tasks are still in execution and the overall status of the release pipeline (rather than individual tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest api has json output, **you can find the status under same level**.

For example, you can find each task status in the task section, i will show more in the script below.

For release status, however it only has below 4 status as per the doc, it cannot show if the release is completed or not. For example, if the release pipeline is completed successfully, or one stage pending on approve, it's still **active** status.

[image]

As a workaround, we can check the deployment status instead, if **anyone** of the deployments has `inProgress` or `notDeployed`, we can consider the pipeline is still `running`. (You can change the condition as per your real release defintion)

PowerShell script as below:

```
# Define the parameters
$organization = "org"
$project = "project"
$releaseId = "releaseid"
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Create the authorization header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$personalAccessToken)))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Invoke the REST API to get the release details
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/release/releases/$releaseId" + "?api-version=7.1"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"

# output release status:
Write-Host "Release: $($response.name)"
Write-Host "Release status: $($response.status)"

foreach ($environment in $response.environments) { 
  # Get the environment name and status 
  $environmentName = $environment.name 
  $environmentStatus = $environment.status

  Write-Host "Environment $environmentName has status $environmentStatus"
  if ($environmentStatus -eq "inProgress" -or $environmentStatus -eq "notDeployed")
  {
   Write-Host "Release is still running"
   break
  }

    # Loop through the tasks in the environment
    foreach ($task in $environment.deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.tasks)
    {
        # Get the task name and status
        $taskName = $task.name
        $taskStatus = $task.status

        # Write the task name and status to the console
        Write-Host "Task $taskName has status $taskStatus"

    }
}
```

The result:

scenario: if one stage is in pending,you can find the release.status is active even one stage is pending on approve.  After checking deployment status, the release is actually still running.

[image]

Senario2: if all stages are completed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! So you mean there is no direct value within the JSON output to identify whether the Release pipeline is success or failure . We have to loop across the status of each task and determine accordingly

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. There are only 4 values for release status, which cannot mean release pipeline is success or failure. You can use sample way as my powershell script, checking all deployment(stage) status instead as it shows the real status.

Comment: Hi @Nandan, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: hey @wadezhou , Can you confirm which output should we consider to check whether the Release pipeline has been executed or not ? Irrespective of whether it is succeed or failed. Just want to know whether the release pipeline is done

Comment: @Nandan, if the release is not executed, there will NOT be a `releaseId` for the rest api, each release has a new releaseId(increased). There is another rest api [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) which can be used to list all releases, if it's not ever run, it will list zero releases.

Comment: I have a release id present. I need to identify whether the release completed or not (irrespective success or failure). So which json output can help it?

Comment: You can check the $environmentStatus for each enviroment make sure there's no inprogress status. Or you can add a new stage at last, check only this stage(environmentstatus) to confirm it's in progress or not.